# Conditionally adding a column in a SQL query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to add a conditional SELECT column in a query and I'm having trouble writing it out:

```sql
SELECT v.GLTypeID,
       v.something,
       v.somethignElse,
       CASE WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 Value FROM InterfaceParam WHERE InterfaceId = 0 AND Descr = 'gf') = 1 THEN a.CreditID ELSE NULL END AS CreditMemoID
FROM vGLDetails2 v
....
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AssociationFund f
        ON v.FundID = f.FundID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.APLedger a ON v.RelID = a.APLedgerID AND v.RelTypeID IN (39, 40)
....
ORDER BY v.Code;
```

The query above works, however if the `CASE` statement is still returning an additional column regardless of the result of the subquery. How can I remove it if the subquery doesn't return a row?

How can I do this?

Comment: `AS` can be applied to a column in the select list only, not to a partial expression.

Comment: Hey, just edited my question!

Comment: A case expression cannot sometimes result in a column and other times not, your question is not clear. You are however selecting one random row from your `InterfaceParam` table which can change on every execution, presumably you're ok with that?

Comment: You cannot. When the subquery returns no record SQL will (or should?) return NULL. This is because the number of columns returned by an SQL script is fixed (by the definition of the SQL statement).

Comment: @Stu Yes, that's fine. Looks like I cannot return a dynamic column then.

Comment: How would your resultset look if you *could* do that when one row had a column and another didn't? It actually looks like you need to run two different queries based on the result of your subquery, `if... else...`

Answer (score 1):

Change the location of `AS`. For example:

```
SELECT v.GLTypeID,
       v.something,
       v.somethignElse,
       CASE WHEN (
         SELECT TOP 1 Value 
         FROM InterfaceParam 
         WHERE InterfaceId = 0 AND Descr = 'creditMemo') = 1 
       THEN a.CreditID     -- AS is not valid here
       END AS CreditMemoID -- AS is valid here
FROM vGLDetails2 v
....
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AssociationFund f
        ON v.FundID = f.FundID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.APLedger a ON v.RelID = a.APLedgerID AND v.RelTypeID IN (39, 40)
....
ORDER BY v.Code;
```

**Note**: I removed `ELSE NULL` since this is the default behavior of `CASE`.

Comment: This worked! However, I'm trying to avoid adding the column if the subqery doesn't return a record now.

Comment: You cannot do that in a simple way. To produce a variable number of columns you can use Dynamic SQL, but that's a whole different ball game. It's simpler to detect the null in the UI and remove the column there.